errror occur at prisma while i used nestjs
npm start

mwa_backend@0.0.1 start
nest start

✔  TSC  Initializing type checker...

TSC  Found 0 issues.
SWC  Running...
Successfully compiled: 43 files with swc (65ms)
[Nest] 5885  - 05/31/2024, 2:44:05 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 5885  - 05/31/2024, 2:44:05 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] @prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again.

try to run pnpm start but got error why

Are you importing the correct prisma client
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

@Injectable()
export class DatabaseService extends PrismaClient implements OnModuleInit {
  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.$connect();
  }
}


thhank you it help me
